# How to access files on SD card through Wi-Fi?

Tags: android, android-wifi

As we know, when Android is connected to a PC through USB cable, the SD card is configured as a mass storage device, and mapped to a drive letter. Thus, a PC program can use the drive letter to access files on the SD card. Now I want to eliminate the use of the cable, and use Wi-Fi instead. My question is:

When a PC and and an Android are on the same router/LAN through Wi-Fi, programmatically, how can a PC program (written in MFC) access the files stored in the SD card?

I know this question is a little too broad, but at this point, all I need is a pointer to a few technologies I need to start looking. Thank you very much.

Comment: are you looking for an existing app like [estrong Filemanager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) wich allows to access SD-Card via FTP? Or are you thinking of an own app that provides an interface?

Comment: I'm thinking about an own app, that when the phone is connected to the Wi-Fi LAN, the MFC program could call some API to access the files on the SD card. Thank you.

Comment: hey!
I know its too late to ask..
But did you get the solution???

Comment: @Awais Tariq, sorry about the late reply. No, I didn't have a solution. I end up doing a Wi-Fi sever on Android, which talks to a client on PC so that the client can do things like findfirst(), findnext(), read(), write(). All using my own protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wwyt,

There is no way to force the Android Device to give away its data from the PC side. It would require at the very least a small Android Application on the device. It was implemented this way on purpose. Mind you the Android Application need not be complex, merely respond to the Wifi connected event and set up the appropriate environment. The PC Application may then run what it needs to get its connection.

There are several applications which utilize this pairing to some degree. EZTether, for instance, utilizes a "swap file" via proxy server to distribute a web connection to the PC side. Such a pairing still requires the full pair, to my knowledge.

In essence, the issue is this: An Android Device cannot be told what to do without intervention by some local counterpart. The local counterpart may be a User or an Application. If its a User, then there must be a Interface by which they can give the correct answer. If it is an application, it must be told to run by either a User or by responding to an event, (system or otherwise). In other words, without cracking the device, one cannot force this issue remotely.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: thank you for the response. This is a very useful pointer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could e.g. implement a web server or ftp server running on the handset, that is serving the files.

Comment: Thank you, but it has to be on the PC side. From a program on PC to read/write files on SD card, when the phone is conected to the Wi-Fi LAN. Thank you.